# How to pimp my (VS2010) editor?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, color-scheme, vssettings

While researching another issue, I came across this: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/sorting-elements-with-jquery/ which made me green with envy for that color scheme (hey, I'm Portuguese).

So I found a .vssettings file online I liked, and tried to install it via "Import and Export Settings" - it has no effect; my "blah" color scheme remains the same (even after restarting VS2010). It's not my process that's wrong, as I was able to do it at home, the only difference being I've got VS2012 there.

So why are the vs-settings settings not getting set? To be more specific, I downloaded wekeroad-ink.vs-settings from http://studiostyl.es/schemes/wekeroad-ink (linked to it from http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/29/download-and-share-visual-studio-color-schemes.aspx).

I select Tools | Import and Export Settings... | Import selected environment settings | Next | Yes, save my current settings | Next | select My Settings | wekeroad-ink.vssettings | Next | Select "All Settings" | Finish | see "Your settings were successfully imported from wekeroad-ink.vssettings." and "To finish the wizard, click Close." | Close, ... no change in my editor colors. Restart VS2010; still no joy.

What's the trick to get it to "take" in VS2010?

Comment: Try [clearing your VS cache](http://www.askamoeba.com/Answer/87/How-to-clear-cache-in-visual-studio-2010)

Comment: I wonder if you need to run VS in Administrator mode? I'll try that (I just thought that at home I always run VS2012 in Admin mode).

Comment: Nope - it still claims to have been imported successfully, but then no actual change...